# Connecting to a second guest from a guest using NAT port forwarding

Tags: virtualbox

I'm having a bear of a time, using VirtualBox, connecting to a 2nd guest from another guest that is using NAT port forwarding.  I've tried setting the second guest to the bridge adapter, but that doesn't seem to work.  I've also read through the documentation, but it confused more than it helped.  I'm pretty terrible at networking, so if anyone can nudge me in a good direction, I'd really be thankful.

Below are pictures of what I'm trying to do & the ipconfig's of the guests:

[image: Picture of Host/Guest Relationships]

[image: ipconfig /all of Guest 1 & 2]